# Product of two functions has Darboux Property (intermediate value property)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f, g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,  such that

- $fg$ has the Intermediate Value Property
- $g$ has also this property
- $f$ is injective

Is it true then that $f$ has also the Intermediate Value Property?

Comment: If $g(x)=0$ the first two properties are trivial.

Comment: @Yanko  ignoring that case

Comment: @Yanko  can you please give me a counter-example?

Comment: I am quite sure that injectivity + IVT implies strict monotonicity, hence (with IVT again) implies continuity.

Comment: @Mindlack  we don’t know that $f$ has IVT

Comment: Yes indeed, but since IVT does not imply continuity at all, this seems a rather strong statement. Indeed $f(x)=sgn(x)(|x|+1)$, and $g(x)=x$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample where $g$ and $fg$ have a strong form of the intermediate value property, namely, each of them takes on all real values in every interval.

**Lemma.** There are sets $A,B\subseteq\mathbb R$ and a function $\varphi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $A\cup B=\mathbb R$, $A\cap B=\emptyset$, and $\varphi(A\cap I)=\varphi(B\cap I)=\mathbb R$ for every interval $I$.

**Proof.** Let $I_1,I_2,I_3,\dots$ enumerate the open intervals with rational endpoints. Construct pairwise disjoint Cantor sets $A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2,A_3,B_3,\dots$ with $A_n,B_n\subseteq I_n$. Let $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ and $B=\mathbb R\setminus A\supseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$. Define $\varphi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ so that $\varphi(A_n)=\varphi(B_n)=\mathbb R$ for every $n$.

Let $A,B\subseteq\mathbb R$ and $\varphi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be as in the Lemma.

Let $h:\mathbb R\to(0,1)$ be injective. Define $f:\mathbb R\to(1,2)\cup(3,4)$ by setting
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
h(x)+1\quad\text{ if }\quad x\in A,\\
h(x)+3\quad\text{ if }\quad x\in B.
\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ is injective and does not have the intermediate value property.

Finally, define $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by setting
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
\varphi(x)\quad\text{ if }\quad x\in A,\\
\frac{\varphi(x)}{f(x)}\quad\ \text{ if }\quad x\in B.
\end{cases}$$
Then for every interval $I$ we have
$$f(I)\supseteq f(A\cap I)=\varphi(A\cap I)=\mathbb R$$
and
$$fg(I)\supset fg(B\cap I)=\varphi(B\cap I)=\mathbb R.$$

Answer (score 1):

Fix a set $A$ of real numbers (for simplicity say $A=(0,1)$).

Choose a function $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is injective and does not have IVT. Extend $f$ to $\mathbb{R}$ arbitrarily such that $f$ is still injective and continuous on $A^c$ (make sure it is also continuous on $0,1$). Now let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be zero on $A$ and continuous.

Then $fg$ is continuous (as it is continuous on $A^c$ and zero on $A$) and so has an IVT.

$g$ is contiuous so it has the IVT.

But $f$ is constructed not to have the IVT on $A$.

Comment: Why is $fg$ continuous?

Comment: @razvanelda because $fg$ is continuous on $A^c$ as product of continuous functions. Also it's zero on $A$. Showing continuity on $0,1$ is easy because as $x$ goes to zero $g(x)$ goes to zero and $f(x)$ goes to $f(0)$ which is constant. The same with $x$ goes to $1$.